# Why are the divs not expanding to the full width of the parent div

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eze5x9t9/

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 65px; background: #00CC00;">
    <div style="width: 60%; overflow: hidden; float: left; background: #3074A3; color: #EDEDED; height: 65px; text-align: center; display: table; vertical-align: middle;">

        <span style="font-size: 35px;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">My Name</span>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 40%; overflow: hidden; float: left; background: #266996; color: #EDEDED; height: 65px; text-align: center; display: table; vertical-align: middle;">
        <span style="font-size: 20px;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">My Job</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Why is there a green space at the end? The fiddle was done in Chrome.

Comment: In Firefox this works as intended, in Chrome interestingly that green pixel line does show up.

Comment: Looks like a rounding error.  If you play with the width of the browser, you can make the green background go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow in Chrome the outer div is exactly one pixel wider than the contained divs.

You could however solve that by not using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` (if you only did that to make the vertical centering work) like so:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 65px; background: #00CC00;">
  <div style="width: 60%; float: left; background: #3074A3; color: #EDEDED; height: 65px; text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size: 35px; line-height: 65px;">My Name</span>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 40%; float: left; background: #266996; color: #EDEDED; height: 65px; text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 65px;">My Job</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit: A second code snippet showcasing the standard method for vertical centering using absolute positioning and `transform: translate`:

```css
.outer {
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #00cc00;
  display: flex;
}
.inner {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  background: #3074A3;
  color: #EDEDED;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  position: relative;
}
.inner + .inner {
  width: 40%;
  background: #266996;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.inner > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <span>My Name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <span>My Job<br />Good job!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing with line-height, is that if the text expands it will not be visible anymore... right?

Comment: If it breaks into several lines, yes.

Comment: I am trying to prevent that. I want it to be as flexible as possible, where if it goes multiple line, the whole thing just moves up.

Comment: Added a second code snippet showcasing the standard method for vertical centering using absolute positioning and `transform: translate`.

Comment: I for the moment did `40.01%` for the second div... to expand but thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common **BUG** for the WebKit browsers, no fixing actually.

reference:

https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2006-January/002684.html

https://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/

http://www.screenr.com/pvB8